# Flutter GetX call fetch data only once in the build methode

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a method called getData() which used to load data from API,
and i am displaying data in a separate screen, I have one issue which whenever I navigate to this page it rebuild the whole screen and call the API again and again.
PS: I'm using getX Obx to control the UI
Question: how to call the function only when new data has added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CategoryPageBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(CategoryPageController(), permanent: true);
  }
}
 

class CategoryPageController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getAllCategories();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method in Controller using getX.

```
 @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getData();
  }
```

Comment: but whenever i enter this screen it rebuilds

Comment: Can you snippet your code?